# How to use Angular material table in angular 8

Tags: angular

I my angular app I want to use Angular Material table with search bar and pagination when i use table not showing properly (no data and loading data is also showing ) how can i use material theme correctly this is the problems any one can help thanks in advance.

[image]

this is component

```
listData : MatTableDataSource<any>;
    @ViewChild(MatSort , {static: false}) sort: MatSort;
    @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) paginator: MatPaginator;
    searchKey: string;
    displayedColumns: string[] = ['index','class','actions'];
    dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
```

This is function

```
 fetchClass()
    {
        return this.classService.getClass().then(
            res => {
                this.listData = new MatTableDataSource(res.data);
                this.listData.sort = this.sort;
                this.listData.paginator = this.paginator;
                //this.classes = res.data;
            },
            err => {
                console.log('Something went Wrong '+ err);
            }
        );
    }
```

this is the html Portion

```
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <div class="search-wrapper">
            <mat-form-field class="search-form-field" floatLabel="never">
                <input matInput [(ngModel)]="searchKey" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off" (keyup)="applyFilter()"
                    class="search-box">
                <button mat-button matSuffix aria-label="Clear" *ngIf="searchKey" (click)="onSearchClear()">
                    <!-- <mat-icon>close</mat-icon> -->
                    <i class="fa fa-close"> </i>
                </button>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
            <mat-table [dataSource]="listData" matSort>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="index">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>S No</mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index ;">{{i + 1}}</mat-cell>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="class">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Class</mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.class}}</mat-cell>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Actions</mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                        <a class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm" (click)="editAppType(element._id)" value="element._id"
                            data-toggle="modal" data-target="#updateAppType"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-edit"></i> Edit
                        </a>
                        <a *ngIf="element.is_deleted == false " class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm ml-1"
                            (click)="onDelete(element._id)"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash"></i> Delete
                        </a>
                    </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="loading">
                    <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef colspan="6">
                        Loading data...
                    </mat-footer-cell>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="noData">
                    <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef colspan="6">
                        No data.
                    </mat-footer-cell>
                </ng-container>

                <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
                <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
                <mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="['loading']" [ngClass]="{'hide':listData!=null}"></mat-footer-row>
                <mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="['noData']"
                    [ngClass]="{'hide':!(listData!=null && listData.data.length==0)}"></mat-footer-row>
            </mat-table>
            <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5,10, 25, 50, 100]" [pageSize]="10" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You're going to have to show us your code and an example of the data.

Comment: Please share your code related to Table and data.

Comment: @Train i have updated code

Comment: @GanganiRoshan i have updated code please go through

Comment: Please clearly mention your problem about material theme or data service?

Comment: I have mention each and every thing where you can not understan @GanganiRoshan